# Is there a way to load a Linux shared library into a specific memory location?

Tags: c, linux, elf, dlopen

I have a Linux application which loads in very small (a few small functions) shared libraries at run-time. For various Important Reasons™ I need the shared libraries to be loaded into a certain virtual memory range. However, `dlopen()` doesn't provide any means (that I can see) to tell it, or hint to it, where to put what it loads.

Is there a way to tell `dlopen()` where it should put the library it loads?

Is there some alternative to `dlopen()` which would provide that functionality?

Comment: I don't believe so, and if there was it would have massive security implications for user-mode applications. Let's assume there is such a function, how would you invoke a function in the library at a specific memory location?

Comment: You should explain the reasons you want this. What is the real motivation and overall goals? Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And I don't see any alternative (except to reimplement dlopen yourself). BTW on Linux you can dlopen many hundred thousands of shared objects in the same process.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What would the "massive security implications" be (assuming the design were sane checked that the address space wasn't already in use by the caller)? `mmap` allows callers to specify a desired address, and that isn't causing any calamity. Windows allows shared libraries to specify their own preferred base address (not guaranteed) without "massive security implications" (ASLR effectiveness is somewhat lessened by Windows' preference for loading all DLLs at the same address in every process but that is so the OS can save memory, not because DLLs can have a preferred image base).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Presumably a hypothetical version of `dlopen()` that takes a target address would still return a handle, which you would then use with `dlsym()` (or similar) to get the address of a specific function. Or something like that. I don't need a specific function to be at a specific address, I just need them all to be within a specific memory region.

Comment: And assuming this mechanism existed, calling functions (or using exported data) wouldn't be a problem at all. `dlsym` would work the same as usual.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Because an attacker could leverage the "well-knownedness" of various library base addresses to perform an attack by overwriting the memory contents at that address. Then a caller (say root) could end up running arbitrary code from the attacker. I agree it's hypothetical, and memory protection mechanisms may well be possible; but that was my concern with the idea.

Comment: If the attacker can overwrite your memory, they've already won. Having a library loaded at a particular address would not make any material difference. Yes, it makes things a *little* easier but I wouldn't call that "massive". I'd reserve that label for the issue that's allowing memory overwrites.

Comment: -1, since you have not edited your question to improve it by explaining the real motivations and goals.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I appreciate your comment. Unfortunately I'm not at liberty to discuss more details regarding _why_ I need to solve this problem, but I can assure you that isn't an XY; this is indeed the problem that I'm trying to tackle.

Comment: Well, if the real problem is to e.g. shadow an existing library or override existing functions - there's other means to do that than loading the library on top of existing code.

Comment: Also see [relocatable code and object files and shared libraries](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2008-10/msg00183.html) (see Ian lance Taylor's reply).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the prelink program may actually demonstrate a way to do this if you are willing to modify the library.  The goal is to modify the library so that it will have a preferred address.  The intent of prelink is to do this for performance, but my suspicion is that it can be modified to work for your use case.
Note that you will never be guaranteed that this will happen in the general case, but in controlled cases you may be able to guarantee that it will happen.
Certainly examining prelink will allow you to understand the parts of elf involved and make a more informed determination about whether it is possible.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelink#
Or see http://packages.qa.debian.org/prelink for the sources in Debian.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the actual problem you are trying to solve.

> For various Important Reasons™

I can only interpret this statement as this is requested to you and you can not do anything about that (i.e. dispute).
So regarding your question:
The loading address has already been specified so you can not change it via this libraries. Actually you need to read about [PIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)
I think the only way to do what you want is to "hack" the libraries and modify the text segment.
Check this out [specify-preferred-load-address](http://shadow-file.blogspot.nl/2012/10/specifying-preferred-load-addresses-for.html).

To be honest you should explain here what is the problem you are trying to solve so you can get answers to help you out in all ways. I.e. so that you can have another option as a solution

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, and `dlopen` (and even any `mmap` *without* `MAP_FIXED`) on recent Linux systems is subject to [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR).

<sup>Consequently, your approach will fail, even if you succeed in doing the equivalent of `dlopen` at some fixed address, unless you disable ASLR system-wide</sup>

In particular two "identical" runs of the same program doing the same `dlopen`-s will go (i.e. have the `dlopen`-ed shared libraries go) into probably different addresses.

Also, on Linux, you can `dlopen` a big lot (at least several hundred thousands) of shared objects. See my [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/maydl.c) as an example

<sup>As I commented, your question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should explain the reasons you want this. What is the real motivation and overall goals?</sup>

You could reimplement your modified `dlopen` yourself by processing the ELF shared object files and do yourself the relocations. You'll also need to compile and link specially your shared object.

If the functions are simple and small (and if you accept a slight decrease in performance relative to `dlopen`-ing small shared libraries compiled with `gcc -fPIC -O2 -shared -Wall`), you could consider using some [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries like [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), [GNU lighting](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), ... to generate the machine code at some fixed address (or simply to generate a call or a jump to the real shared library function)

BTW, you might use and adapt to your weird needs the [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) (it includes a `dlopen` function which you could port to your needs)